# Illegal use of floating point

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a code that calculates monthly pay for a project.

This is the formula I was given:

```
(Rate + Rate/((1+Rate)^Months)-1) * Principle
```

`Rate` according to this formula is `Rate/1200` so as an example if the rate is `7%` it would be `7/1200` which is `0.00583333333`. I'm trying to get the exact number `0.00583333333` into my program but then I get the error "illegal use of floating point".

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    float r;
    int m, y;
    int p;
    //int mp;


    printf("Enter Rate: ");
    scanf("%d", &r);
    r = r%1200;

    printf("Enter number of years: ");
    scanf("%d", &y);
    m = y*12;  

    printf("%.10lf\n",r);
    printf("%d",m);

    return 0;
}
```

How do I get `0.00583333333` to be a part of my calculation in the program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to change `scanf("%d", &r);` by `scanf("%f", &r);` and `r = r%1200` by `r = r/1200`

Comment: Declaring 'r' as a 'double' instead of 'float' will give you the precision you need. Also you will have to use scanf("%lf", &r) when reading ... since you require that level of precision in 'r'.